# UNKNOWN when using def's

Tags: z3

This simple example generates UNKNOWN for me, I suppose there is something that I don't understand about def's.

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
def Min(b, r): 
    return If(b, r, 1)
a = Real('a')
b = Bool('b')

s.add(a==0.9)
s.add(a<=Min(b,0.9))

s.check()   
print "Presenting result "
m = s.model()
print "traversing model..."
for d in m.decls():
    print "%s = %s" % (d.name(), m[d])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not make any mistake. This is a problem in one of Z3 solvers. Your problem is in a fragment of arithmetic called "difference-logic". A problem in in this fragment, if the arithmetic atoms can be written as `x - y <= k`, where `k` is a numeral. When a problem is in this fragment, Z3 will use a specialized solver for it. However, this solver may fail (returns `unknown`) when the input problem also contains  if-then-else terms (the `If` in your `Min`).
[The bug has been fixed](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/39d5b850e80a), and will be available in the next release. In the meantime, you can try one of the following workarounds:

- Force Z3 to eliminate if-then-else terms before invoking the solver. You just have to replace `s = Solver()` with `s = Then('elim-term-ite', 'smt').solver()`. [Here is the modified script at rise4fun.](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/ruJC)
- We can add a redundant assertion that is not in the different logic fragment. Example: `z + w > 2`. [Here is the modified script at rise4fun.](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/URlO)